# Intel iGPU and Xubuntu jitter

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, intel-graphics, gpu

I just recently purchased an Intel i7 4790k CPU and installed Xubuntu shortly after. A lot of things seem to work correctly however the HD 4600 of the 4790k seems to struggle a little bit. Moving window causes jitter and tearing.

Is there a way to fix this or at least see where the problem lies?

`sudo lshw -C display` output seems to be ok.

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:df800000-dfbfffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: Could you add please the output of `sudo lshw -C display` [to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/596456/edit)?

Comment: @Wilf sure, I added it. the clock looks a little bit slow :\

Comment: nah just got a new i3 netbook with similar integrated graphics - works much better than my old i5 with AMD discrete.... Your answer below is probably due to the monitor or something if its refresh rates

Comment: No, the Intel HD 4600 seems to be not supported very well. But I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Enable Synchronize drawing to the vertical blank**

You can find this option under your System Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Compositor if you have Xubuntu. I don't know where in other distros. This option basically means some kind of vertical synchronization when drawing.

**2. Create & edit xorg.conf**

Create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` if it doesn't exit and add:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver     "intel"
    Option     "AccelMethod"    "sna"
    Option     "TearFree"       "true" 
EndSection
```

**3. If first 2 steps didn't work**

While setting up a Nvidia Graphics Card for a friend I noticed that the `xorg.conf` is not always enough. Sometimes changing the compositor helps. In his case I switched the standard Xubuntu compositor to "compton". Things worked fine after that.

Restart and you should be fine.